# Mongoose querying mongodb for a given date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have tried a couple of options to retrieve records on a given date specifically today's date as seen below. I still get 0 records.

```
 const coins = await Coin.find({
  lastVoted: {
    $gte: new Date(2021, 7, 5),
    $lt: new Date(2021, 7, 7),
  },
})
 const coins = await Coin.find({
      approved: true,
      lastVoted: new Date(2021, 7, 7),
      
    })
```

Comment: the query syntax you posted here is fine, you're having a different issue.
either the connection is wrong or you don't have any matching documents in the collection, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, if found that [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) does the job fine. This is how I did it

```
const timeOfDay = require('date-fns')
const coins = await Coin.find({
      
      lastVoted: {
        $gte: timeOfDay.startOfDay(new Date()),
        $lt: timeOfDay.endOfDay(new Date()),
      },
    })
```